# How do I create a '4 or 5 Alembic-Size' 'Label Free' essentia distributor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

Thaumcraft 4 makes use of essentia tubes that work off of a suction system that only allows one type of essentia to move through a tube at a time. This system makes networks difficult and tricky. I want a system that works like so:

- I will have an Alchemical Furnace smelting items with 4 or 5 aspects into essentia, which is then distributed to 4 or 5 Alembics.
- I want to be able to place my items to smelt and fuel in the furnace, place some empty and unlabeled* (*is this possible?) jars connected to the system, and walk away.
- I want the system to sort out the essentia produced and deliver it to the jars ONLY using the piping system, including buffers and advanced pipes such as directional and restricted and the like. ( I do NOT want to use Golems, nor do I want to use pre-labeled Alembics)

Things I have tried:

- Detail: The Jars may HAVE to be prelabeled as there seems to be no other way to guarantee any one essentia type won't distribute to all the jars before the rest of the types can reach them.
- Second Detail: I just remembered that arcane bellows can be attached to buffers to increase their suction, this creates for interesting new ideas!
- I have built a system that currently works for items that have only two aspects, however this is not ideal, I want a system that works with at least 4 aspects. I will include details of this system in future edits to help brainstorm.
- Various buffer placements, more experimenting will be done to further flesh out possible buffer options, but for now I've tried the system described below with buffers connected to each alembic before each line, and connecting the lines at various places. This isn't the right track neccesarily because the buffers aren't providing the proper suction to work together across multiple pipelines.
- Connecting each alembic to an individual jar via a single tube connected to nothing else. This works if the alembics are pre-labeled and only if they are pre-labeled. If the alembics are not pre-labeled there is no guarantee the essentia that was just pulled out of it will match the essentia going in so you end up with a jar that has for example 8 terra connected to an alembic that is now receiving perdito.

This is my current setup that allows me to sort up to 3 types, if I'm not mistaken a modification to this with additional buffers leading to additional bottles may be a solution if I use bellows to help things along.  Currently I have each Alembic outputting to a buffer, which then feeds into vertical shafts leading to my warded jars.

[image: Essentia Distribution Machine]
Edit Note: In time I will include screenshots and detailed descriptions of my previously failed attempts.

Comment: Have you considered using Thaumic Energistics? It allows you to import and export essentia to the ME network, therefore allowing you to just throw all your newly created essentia into a bin and take it out whenever you need it.

Comment: @Logikable Have you considered reading my question, which specifies I would like my solutions to remain within Thaumcraft's Alchemical Apparatus?